# Table overflow-x does not have horizontal scrollbar in hierarchy of DIVs with a Flex top parent

Tags: html, css

I have an outer container DIV which is centered with a Flex (`display:flex`,`justify-content:center`) and somewhere among its descendants a Table whose immediate wrapper DIV has an `overflow-x:auto` horizontal scrollbar to support horizontal table scrolling.

Example 2 works correctly both from the starting point and as you resize the window. The table starts out centered and if you resize, once you overflow, you'll see the horizontal scrol bar. In this example, the Table is directly under the Container Flex-centered parent.

But I have Example 1 with a deeper hierarchy, with just a few DIVs added. Now when you resize, the table doesn't obey the overflow and doesn't show the scroll bar anymore.

Note: Run on a **full page** to see only Table 2 having the scrollbar on resizing. I need to keep the Flex Top Parent so that the outer container is centered, but I don't want it to apply to the Table's wrapper with the `overflow-x`.

```css
.tableWrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
     <div>
        <div class="tableWrapper">

          <table>
             <thead>
               <th>Column 1</th>
               <th>Column 2</th>
               <th>Column 3</th>
               <th>Column 4</th>
               <th>Column 5</th>
               <th>Column 6</th>
               <th>Column 7</th>
               <th>Column 8</th>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>1111111</td><td>2222222</td><td>33333333</td><td>444444444</td><td>55555555</td><td>6666666</td><td>77777777</td><td>88888888</td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 
 <br/><br/><br/>
 
 <div class="container">
        <div class="tableWrapper">

          <table>
             <thead>
               <th>Column 1</th>
               <th>Column 2</th>
               <th>Column 3</th>
               <th>Column 4</th>
               <th>Column 5</th>
               <th>Column 6</th>
               <th>Column 7</th>
               <th>Column 8</th>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>1111111</td><td>2222222</td><td>33333333</td><td>444444444</td><td>55555555</td><td>6666666</td><td>77777777</td><td>88888888</td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra `<div>` will grow to it content size, which is too large so the table isn't centered anymore, and the `overflow: scroll` on the deeper element has nothing to scroll.

Add `overflow: auto` to the extra div to forward it.

```css
.tableWrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.extra-container {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="extra-container">
     <div>
        <div class="tableWrapper">

          <table>
             <thead>
               <th>Column 1</th>
               <th>Column 2</th>
               <th>Column 3</th>
               <th>Column 4</th>
               <th>Column 5</th>
               <th>Column 6</th>
               <th>Column 7</th>
               <th>Column 8</th>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>1111111</td><td>2222222</td><td>33333333</td><td>444444444</td><td>55555555</td><td>6666666</td><td>77777777</td><td>88888888</td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 
 <br/><br/><br/>
 
 <div class="container">
        <div class="tableWrapper">

          <table>
             <thead>
               <th>Column 1</th>
               <th>Column 2</th>
               <th>Column 3</th>
               <th>Column 4</th>
               <th>Column 5</th>
               <th>Column 6</th>
               <th>Column 7</th>
               <th>Column 8</th>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>1111111</td><td>2222222</td><td>33333333</td><td>444444444</td><td>55555555</td><td>6666666</td><td>77777777</td><td>88888888</td>
               </tr>
             </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But now when I run your snippet on the full page, Table 1 isn't centered anymore. It was centered in my post. In fact, if I remove the `full-width` class it becomes centered again.

Comment: Yep, should have tested it more. I've changed my answer, forget that width, an overflow property seems to be enough.

Comment: Thanks, so it's just on 1 child inner DIV, not all of them?

Comment: Yes, the second div will inherit it from the first iirc, maybe it's cleaner to add it there as well tho ;0